# Joda time localization - getAsText(Locale..) is not working correctly with some locales

Tags: android, localization, jodatime

`getAsText()` supposed to print a localized version, according to the device Locale:

When the locale is `en` for example, everything is ok:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText()); 
| Tuesday
```

but if changing the syslem language to Hebrew for example, it's broken:

```
System.out.println(dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText()); 
| 3        ( <-- supposed to be "יום שלישי")
```

If overriding device locale, still some locales seem not to work:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText(Locale.FRENCH)); // prints "mardi" = OK
System.out.println(dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText(new Locale("iw"))); // prints "3"
| mardi
| 3        ( <-- supposed to be "יום שלישי")
```

When changing system locale to iw, this code prints correctly, meaning the translation *is* available somewhere:

```
System.out.println(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, dt, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY)); 
| יום שלישי
```

Making sure the Locale is available:

```
Locale iw = new Locale("iw");
System.out.println(iw.getDisplayName() + " " + iw.toString()); // prints Hebrew iw == OK
| Hebrew iw
```

Any advice how to fix this, and make sure joda time getAsText/getAsShortText will get localized? 
(Or how to add my translations?)

**update 1**

One direction I try for fixing this problem, is to add missing translations manually.

In `SimpleDateFormat` it's possible to add/edit names of days, months or other symbols, using get and set of `DateFormatSymbols`. Works great - but not in Joda.

In Joda I could find only the "get" part, and I can't find how to set it back...

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols(iw); // << joda method
dfs.setWeekdays(new String[] { "ראשון", "שני", "שלישי", "רביעי", "חמישי","שישי", "שבת" });
```

Any idea how to set DateFormatSymbols back to the formatter ?

**update 2**

Drilling into Joda code I realize it's impossible to set back.
The reason for the problem lies in `java.text.DateFormatSymbols(Locale)` constructor.
Apparently, some locales do not contain all the needed information inside

```
libcore.icu.LocaleData.get(locale);
```

As a result, the data defaults to numeric values.
The problem seem to exist in older devices, as new Android versions add the missing information.

bottom line: Joda formatter is *unreliable* when using non mainstream languages on older Android versions. (Tested on v. 11). On recent version - it is more reliable.

Comment: FYI here's a link with a mapping between Android versions and supported ICU locale data: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization.html